# VBA, get and manage the active web page after browser closing and re-opening

Tags: vba, ms-access, html

in my Access & VBA application i Have to get and manage a web page of a web order application. Normally, I use the solution indicated in this post, which normally works perfectly:

[VBA Open web page, login and get the opened page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43569876/vba-open-web-page-login-and-get-the-opened-page/43570071#43570071)

But, now I have another old web application to connect with my Access software. In this web application, after login, the web page closes itself and open an other browser session with the first user page. In other words:

1) The user fill the login form with the user credentials
2) After login, the login web page closes the browser
3) An other browser session opens with the web app control panel

If I use the linked solution, I see an error. How can I get the new web page, in the new browser session, which opens it self after login?

Thanks!

EDIT

I have tried the following code (my purpose is set a text value in the web page). But, very strange, it works only if I put a text box in my code: maybe the code must wait some event! How can I solve it?

```html
Dim SWs As SHDocVw.ShellWindows, vIE As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim winShell As Shell
Dim dt As Date
dt = DateAdd("s", 10, DateTime.Now)
Dim ieA As InternetExplorer
Dim IeDocA As HTMLDocument
Do While dt > DateTime.Now

   Set winShell = New Shell

   For Each ieA In winShell.Windows
       If ieA.LocationURL = sURL Then

       ieA.Visible = True
       ieA.Silent = True

       Do While ieA.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
       Do Until ieA.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop
       Set IeDocA = ieA.Document
       
       //only with this msgbox it works, how can I do this w/out it?       
       MsgBox IeDocA.title

       With IeDocA
             .getElementsByName("text").value="something"
       End With

       Set winShell = Nothing
       Exit Do

       End If

   Next ieA
   Set winShell = Nothing
   DoEvents

Loop
```

Answer (score 2):

You can Look for the URL in the window.  You will need a reference to Microsoft Shell Controls and Automation.

```
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'Desc: The Function gets the Internet Explorer window that has the current
'   URL from the sURL Parameter.  The Function Timesout after 30 seconds
'Input parameters:
    'String sURL - The URL to look for
'Output parameters:
    'InternetExplorer ie - the Internet Explorer window holding the webpage
'Result: returns the the Internet Explorer window holding the webpage
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Public Function GetWebPage(sUrl As String) As InternetExplorer
Dim winShell As Shell
Dim dt As Date
dt = DateAdd("s", 30, DateTime.Now)

Dim ie As InternetExplorer

Do While dt > DateTime.Now
    Set winShell = New Shell
    'loop through the windows and check the internet explorer windows
    For Each ie In winShell.Windows
        'check the URL
        If ie.LocationURL = sUrl Then
            'set some properties
            ie.Visible = True
            ie.Silent = True
            Set GetWebPage = ie
            'loop while IE is busy
            Do While ie.Busy
                DoEvents
            Loop
            Set winShell = Nothing
            Exit Do

        End If
    Next ie
    Set winShell = Nothing
    DoEvents
Loop
End Function
```

Comment: Interesting solution! Tomorrow I will try in the real application, and I let you know.

Comment: First, sorry for the delay! I was not in Italy. Second, I have edited my post. Can you please read it? Thank you very much!